# 1045 access denied for phpmyadmin over lan but not on desktop

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have phpmyadmin installed on CentOS 6 and I can log in to it using `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` on a browser on the server's desktop just fine, but when I try `http://192.168.254.5/phpmyadmin` from my laptop, I get

Error #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have checked the settings in config.inc.php

- auth_type is 'cookie', and I have a 41-character string in
  blowfish_secret
- host is '127.0.0.1' per the documentation at
  wiki.phpmyadmin.net (also tried 'localhost' and '192.168.254.5')

I have entered `mysql -uroot -pmypassword` and succesfully logged in using an ssh window on my laptop to be sure it's typed correctly and then cut and pasted mypassword into the phpmyadmin login form on the laptop's browser.

Oddly enough, when I try logging in to `http://192.168.254.5/phpmyadmin` from the browser on the server's desktop, I get

Error #2003 the server is not responding

But I can enter `mysql -uroot -pmypassword -h 192.168.254.5` from a terminal window on the server or from another linux system on the lan and log in.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange. It has magically fixed itself %-(

It occurred to me that in case it was some bizarre SELinux issue, I should to try again from the laptop and then look in dmesg; however, this time it let me log in just fine.